# Derivative with respect to vector

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, vectors, hamiltonian-formalism, differentiation

How in Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics we take derivatives with respect to velocity and momentum respectively if they are vectors? Can we take derivative with respect to a vector?

Comment: You can certainly take derivatives with respect to components of the vector. Often this is enough. Problems begin if you want to have some sort of coordinate-independent approach. Then @Darkseid answer applies

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking we can only take a "covariant" derivative of a vector, for which we need to use a Affine connection (Christoffel symbols) for particular manifold/coordinate system we are doing physics on.

In the flat space and Cartesian coordinates the Christoffel symbols are identically zero. Thus regular derivatives could be taken and are automatically covariant.

In the curvilinear coordinates or on a curved manifold, it is not immediately obvious that Lagrange equations are covariant. However, it can be shown (see some differential geometry textbook, like [one by Frankel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107602602)) that they **are** covariant.